# Corner radius for a navigation bar

Tags: iphone

i have developed an iPad app. In that app i have 4 separate views embedded inside a single view controller and there is a navigation bar for each view.I want to set the corner radius of each navigation bar.

i tried

```
       customNavigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
```

but this piece of code is not working. Does anyone know how to set the corner radius for each navigation bar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
customNavigationBar.layer.cornerRadius=25;
customNavigationBar.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

i have tested it successfully

Comment: This solution doesn't work well if you have background colour set and wish to keep status bar in the same colour. clipsToBounds prevents UINavigationBar from covering status bar, it ends on safe area.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4:**
Also if you only want the **top edges of the navigation bar to have rounded corners**, you can try this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working on Swift 4. Nothing happened to it. Sure it worked?

Comment: This is for  iOS 11 onwards, which version are you checking with. worth checking this answer for iOS 10 and below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49731708/5438240

Comment: Thanks @Naishta, I was trying to round out the NavigationBar only, but I completely forgot that I use the NavigationBar under the TabBar !! So it never got round. Now it's rounded :) Thanks for your message !! Helped me shift focus to TabBar!

Comment: This cuts navigationBar in half

Answer (score 2):

Add an image with corner rounded as background of navigation bar to make it happen. Check this link [Applying rounded corners for the whole application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735969/applying-rounded-corners-for-the-whole-application)

Answer (score 1):

add quartcore framework and than

in .h file of header

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and write code as below

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius=25;
```