# Round Top Corners of a UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rounded-corners

I know I can round all four corners using:

```
 myBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
 myBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Since I only want to round two, I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview/10167334#10167334):

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
view.roundCorners([.TopLeft , .TopRight], radius: 10)
```

Yet this doesn't work for a UIButton. When I switch the extension to be for type UIButton and pass it a button , the output looks like this:

[image]

The question is, how do I adapt this to work on a UIButton?

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer, because it is the most precise answer to the problem. Future visitors of this question will not be satisfied just by seeing a bunch of code that works, but does not explain why it works (that's what the currently accepted answer does) but rather by seeing _where_ the problem is – and that is nailed down by my answer.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40222533/2594699

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Adding Extension of UIButton:**

```
extension UIButton{
    func roundedButton(){
        let maskPath1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight],
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPath1.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }
}
```

**Calling in viewDidAppear/viewDidLayoutSubviews:**

```
btnCorner.roundedButton()
```

**Button Corner OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can remove this from the button after? If I want to reuse the button but without rounding? NVM, here it is:                 myBtn.layer.mask?.removeFromSuperlayer()

Comment: Doesn't work for when buttons are in stack view. When rounding corner bottom left and right corners, it rounds only bottom left corner. When using buttons that are not embedded in a stack view, it works totally fine

Comment: Using the frame like this will not work when resizing the button. e.g. adding the button to a UIStackView.

Comment: How can I round all 4 corners with this extension?

Answer (score 65):

**Swift 4: For latest iOS 11 onwards**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.viewToRound.clipsToBounds = true
        viewToRound.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        viewToRound.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

**Earlier iOS (10,9 etc) Versions (works for iOS 11 too)**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.viewToRound.clipsToBounds = true
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewToRound.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft],
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    viewToRound.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Answer (score 20):

For **swift 3**  Kirit Modi's answer is changed to:

```
extension UIButton {
   func roundedButton(){
       let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight],
                                    cornerRadii:CGSize(width:8.0, height:8.0))
       let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
       maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
       maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
       self.layer.mask = maskLayer1
   }
}
```

At the start of the extension's file don't forget to add:

```
import UIKit
```

If you want an extension for a **UIView** with the option of rounding top or bottom corners you can use:

```
extension UIView {
   func roundedCorners(top: Bool){
       let corners:UIRectCorner = (top ? [.topLeft , .topRight] : [.bottomRight , .bottomLeft])        
       let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                    cornerRadii:CGSize(width:8.0, height:8.0))
       let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
       maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
       maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
       self.layer.mask = maskLayer1
   }
}
```

Which is called for a button as:

```
myButton.roundedCorners(top: true)
```

Answer (score 12):

iOS 11 has made it really easy to round corners. The code below rounds the top left and bottom right corners.

```
myView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

Comment: Thanks ..
/* Defines which of the four corners receives the masking when using
 * `cornerRadius' property. Defaults to all four corners. */

.button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            button.layer.masksToBounds = true
            button.clipsToBounds = true
            button.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]

Answer (score 9):

For **swift 5** and the most flexibility

**Define an extension with a roundCorners function**

```
extension UIButton {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: Int = 8) {
        let maskPath1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPath1.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }
}
```

**Call the roundCorners function**

```
myButton.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
```

[image]

**Or with a specific radius**

```
myButton.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
```

[image]

Comment: how to set shadow to these buttons with [.topLeft , .topRight] ?

Comment: Using the frame like this will not work when resizing the button. e.g. adding the button to a UIStackView.

Answer (score 6):

Update you extension to be like this:

```
extension UIView {
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    let rect = self.bounds
    mask.frame = rect
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
}
```

The shape layer (mask) needs to know the frame

Comment: thanks for the code, it is quite usefull in many scenarios. but please change "maskLayer.frame = rect" to "mask.frame = rect"

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code,

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:viewTo.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
viewTo.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

hope its helpful

Comment: bro - the questioner already called the method like `view.roundCorners([.TopLeft , .TopRight], radius: 10)`, can you modify your answer once

Comment: ya i know questioner ask but this above code is correct

Answer (score 2):

That's what helped me

```
extension UIView {

   func roundCorners(
      corners: UIRectCorner, 
      radius: CGFloat
   ) {
      let path = UIBezierPath(
         roundedRect: bounds,
         byRoundingCorners: corners,
         cornerRadii: CGSize(
            width: radius, 
            height: radius
         )
      )

      let mask = CAShapeLayer()
      mask.path = path.cgPath
      layer.mask = mask
   }
}
```

Pay attention to the fact that if you have layout constraints attached to it, you must refresh this as follows in your UIView subclass:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   yourButtonOutletName.roundCorners(
      corners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
      radius: yourButtonOutletName.frame.height / 2
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the frame of your shape layer:

```
mask.frame = layer.bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

rounding is applied to corner's of view/Button .. , but coming to border of button , it is not applying correctly. can I have any solution for that? @

Here is the code that I have used , which is working (border) in iOS11.0 and above and not in below versions(<11.0)

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.maskedCorners = maskedCorners
    } else {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.position = self.center
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        let bezirePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                      byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                      cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        shapeLayer.bounds = frame
        shapeLayer.path = bezirePath.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: Using the frame like this will not work when resizing the button. e.g. adding the button to a UIStackView.