# UIButton disappears when round left corner

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rounded-corners, cashapelayer

**I want to round only the bottom left corner of a button, but the button disappears from view when I implement the below code.**

**Code**

```
    cancelBtn.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.ecaftRed, for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cancelBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteFadedPlus.cgColor
    cancelBtn.roundBtnCorners([.bottomLeft], radius: 25)
    cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    popUpView.addSubview(cancelBtn)

    cancelBtn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.left.equalTo(popUpView)
        make.bottom.equalTo(popUpView)
        make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 0.5*popUpView.frame.width, height: 0.25*popUpView.frame.height))
    }


extension UIButton{

    func roundBtnCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37164147/7327018)

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me.. show your `cancelBtn` code..

Comment: It seems that your code works

Comment: The bounds of your button might be zero.

Comment: @Brandon I updated the frame and it worked thank you!

Comment: @Brandon Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The bounds of your button is most likely zero or close to zero. So the button won't show OR the mask will mask the entire thing.