# Modal MFMailComposeViewController doesn't respond to touches in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My iOS app contains rounded corners for the whole application (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735969/applying-rounded-corners-for-the-whole-application))

```
UIImage *overlayImg;

int offset;

if(IS_IPHONE_5) {
    overlayImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rounded4inch.png"];
    offset = 548;
} else {
    overlayImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rounded.png"];
    offset = 461;
}

CALayer *overlay = [CALayer layer];
overlay.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, overlayImg.size.width,offset);
overlay.contents = (id)overlayImg.CGImage;
overlay.zPosition = 1;
[self.window.layer addSublayer:overlay];
```

But now my modal MFMailComposeViewController doesn't respond to touches. I cannot edit the input fields, send the mail, or dismiss it. It's just frozen and doesn't respond to touches.

Comment: an unrelated hint: you only need one small 50x50px image for all screen sizes. just use a resizable image. (`resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`)

Comment: @jaydee3 great hint but that doesn't solve the layering problem that prevents touch input for the mail controller ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior.
Never any problem got resolved for me by restarting the device, but this time it did. Strange.

I have the iOS 6.0 GM installed, not the over-the-air install. Maybe an issue with the GM.

Comment: GM = released final version. they have the same build number.

Comment: rebooting the device didn't work for me. I've got the same behavior in the simulator though.

Comment: have you tried to use an additional window instead of a sublayer on the mainwindow? (and are the touches working, when you remove your extra layer?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to hide the layer after displaying the modal mail composer

```
    [delegate.navigationController presentViewController:mfViewController animated:YES completion:^void() {
        CALayer* layer = (CALayer*)[delegate.window.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:1];
        [layer setHidden:YES];
    }];
```

and reshow it after the modal view is dismissed

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^void() {
    CALayer* layer = (CALayer*)[delegate.window.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:1];
    [layer setHidden:NO];
}];
```